# Как сделать отдельный clicklistener для каждого элемента item в listView?

Tags: android, android-fragment, adapter, listview

У меня в `item` находится 3 элемента, но при нажатии на него выделяется полностью вся строчка. Мне нужно, чтобы каждый элемент `item` кликался отдельно.

Подскажите, как к адаптеру сделать `setOnClickListener` правильно?

```
public class MountainFragment extends ListFragment {
public final static String TAG = MyTag.TAG_MOUNTAIN;
private MountainShop mountainShop = new MountainShop();

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    List<HashMap<String, String>> listMountainShop = new ArrayList<>();

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setLastFragmentTag(this.getClass().toString());

    for (int i = 0; i < mountainShop.getListShops().size(); i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();

        hm.put("img", Integer.toString(mountainShop.getIconShops().get(i)));
        hm.put("txt", mountainShop.getListShops().get(i));
        hm.put("imgMy", Integer.toString(R.drawable.ic_control_point_black_24dp));
        listMountainShop.add(hm);
    }

    String[] from = {"img", "txt", "imgMy"};
    int[] to = {R.id.imgForList, R.id.textForList, R.id.imgForMyList};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), listMountainShop, R.layout.list_single, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_mountain);
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mountainShop.getLinkShop(position)));
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Создавайте свой класс, который будет наследоваться от класса ArrayAdapter в нём в методе getView() через LayoutInflater инфлейтите свою вьюху и у нею достаёте нужные вам элементы через findViewById(), которым и назначаете листенеры. Про ViewHolder не забывайте.

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
   private Button btnOne;
   private TextView tvTwo;
   private TextView tvThree;

   public CustomAdapter (Context context, int resource, ArrayList<MusicData> array) {
     super(context, resource, array);
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup p) {
      View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);
      btnOne = view.findViewById(R.id.imgForList);
      tvTwo = view.findViewById(R.id.textForList);
      tvThree = view.findViewById(R.id.R.id.imgForMyList);
      btnOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

           }
      });
      tvTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

           }
      });
      tvThree.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

           }
      });
      return view;
   }
  }
```

немного адаптируйте для себя и всё

Comment: Спасибо, зделал.

Comment: на самом деле так не надо делать. Лучше определить один глобальный листенер, а в нем по ID разделить нажимаемые view, а уже для каждой вьюхи передать в тэги необходимую информацию, чтобы как-то её обработать при клике.
в таком варианте, представьте сколько лишних объектов вы нагенерили

Comment: дело вкуса не более

Answer (score 0):

Сделал свой адаптер. В конструкторе получаю свой список, и потом с него сечу в свои элементы:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
private final List object;
private ImageView imgIcon;
private TextView nameShop;
private ImageView imgPlus;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.object = objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_single, null);

    HashMap<String, String> list = (HashMap<String, String>) object;

    imgIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgForList);
    imgIcon.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(list.get("img")));

    nameShop = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textForList);
    nameShop.setText(list.get("txt"));

    imgPlus = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgForMyList);
    imgPlus.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(list.get("imgMy")));

    imgIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(MyTag.TEST, "1");
        }
    });

    nameShop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(MyTag.TEST, "2");
        }
    });

    imgPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(MyTag.TEST, "3");
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: "с него сечу в свои элементы" - не совсем понял, что это озночает.